# Диалоговое окно javascript

Tags: javascript

Как при нажатии на кнопку вызвать диалоговое окно javascript? Например, нажали на удалить - вылезло окно: "Удалить? - Да. Нет."

Comment: Вы бы хоть гугль открыли перед тем как задавать столь "сложные" вопросы.. (

Comment: Не доводилось как то.

Comment: Стоит начинать именно с этого ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фукнкция:

```
function show_confirm() { 
    confirm("Удалить?");
}
```

Кнопка:

```
<input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Удалить" />
```

Comment: Ну, и проверка: if(confirm("Удалить?")){/*пользователь нажал ok*/}